# Return a variable in my model if the query returns true

Tags: php, codeigniter

## Model

```
  $q = $this->db->get_where('person', array('p_id' => $p));
  if($q->num_rows()!=1) 
    {
    redirect('General_Area/Home');
    exit();
    }
    else
    {   
         . . .
```

Ok So once the model is initialized it queries the db and looks for exactly one match and if found it moves on the else statement. However if not found it will `redirect('General_Area/Home');`

How do I pass a message in there? In my controller I am returning an `object` if the query is successful.

And in my view i am `echo obj->table_col_name`

```
  $q = $this->db->get_where('person', array('p_id' => $p));
  if($q->num_rows()!=1) 
    {
    return $Error = 'You have not been found!...';
    #redirect('General_Area/Home');
    exit();
    }
    else
    {   
         . . .
```

If the `$q` was not successful I want to be able to `echo $error;` in the view for the user to see the message.

Comment: A message to where, in the controller ?

Comment: Well it should make its way back to the view so that user can see it..

Comment: I feel like this is really simple. Somebody must know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to pass a message with the object on successful query result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In your Model

```
if($q->num_rows()>0)
{
    return array('result'=>$q->result(), 'message'=>'This is a message');
}
return false;
```

### In the Controller

```
$this->load->model('your_model_name');
$data['query']=$this->your_model_name->model_function_name();
if(!$data['query']['result'])
{
    redirect('General_Area/Home');
    exit();
}
else $this->load->view('your_view_name',$data);
```

### In your View

```
if(isset($query))
{
    foreach($query as $row)
    {
        // code goes here to echo columns
    }
    //and message is available as $message so you can print it like
    if(isset($message)) echo $message;
}
```

### Message on redirect

Also if you want to send a message when you redirect to another page you can use in your controller

```
if(!$data['query']['result'])
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'your message text here!');
    redirect('General_Area/Home');
    exit();
}
```

So you can print the message in the view like

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Read more about [Flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Comment: Ok awesome answer -- great options. +1 on the flashdata -- very cool!