# Codeigniter random row mysql error- Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, random

```
function random()
    {
    $anketadb = $this->load->database('anketa',TRUE);
    $br = $anketadb->count_all_results('anketadata');
    $nmb = mt_rand(1,$br);

    if ($nmb != 1){
    $nmb = $nmb - 1;
    }

    $count = $anketadb->get('anketadata', 1, $nmb);

    return $count;
    }
```

> Why this code when i echo it in View returns ERROR:
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to
>   string
>
> Filename: ankete/rezultatiankete.php
>
> Line Number: 52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have shown us more code (controller, view etc), anyways, in your example you are using

```
return $count;
```

in this case `$count;` is an object and to echo it's fields you have to loop in your view like

```
foreach ($count->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->fieldname; // rerplace the fieldname with a real field/column name of your database
}
```

so if you are trying to echo the `$count` then you are making a mistake, it's an object, [**read more here**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: Yes, inside the foreach just echo the column name like `echo $row->fieldname;`

Comment: But this is in Model , so in View can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Are you loading it from a controller ?

Comment: Yes, I am loading view from controller, the controller part is not a problem

Comment: [Here is another similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888092/return-a-variable-in-my-model-if-the-query-returns-true/12888250#12888250).

Answer (score 0):

`echo` doesnot work for objects use `print_r(returned value)` to output objects,arrays

to fetch a random column use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;`

Comment: If i use print_r its print something like this:

'CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [client_info] => 5.1.52 [client_version] => 50152 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [field_count] => 15 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.1.61-log [server_version] => 50161 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 18494924 [warning_count] => 0 ) [resul.....'

Comment: what details you want from database

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;