# Fetching information from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, xampp

MY UPDATED QUESTION IS HERE:

[Fetching information from the database MYSQL & Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337696/fetching-information-from-the-database-mysql-codeigniter)

please see :)

---

I just want to ask what's the problem with this code. I've been trying to figure this out since last night. And I again, i'm posting this question. There's something wrong with my syntax I guess.

```
function member_here()
{
    $this->db->select('');
    $this->db->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
    $q=$this->db->get('');

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array();
        foreach($q->result() as $row) {
            $data=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

So anyway. The output for that would be selected information from the database.

**but**

I figured that some parts of the code is correct because it is giving an output. But its still not right.

lets say i have this data:

```
|-------Name-----|-----Username-----|---------Email Address----------|
|     Marishka   |   marishkapv     |    marishka@email.com          |
|     John       |   johndoe        |   john@doe.com                 |
|     Dennis     |   dennisv        |     dennis@v.com               |
```

So, I logged in using Marishka.
After the successful log in. The information I see in my home page is **the information of dennis**

Same with if I log in **john**

The data being fetched from the database is the last data stored. How can I select from the database which belongs to the specific username i logged in

Please answer. Thank you so much!

**HERE'S AN UPDATE**

this is the code in my view form

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('membership_model');
$result = $CI->membership_model->member_here();
?>


User Information:

</br></br></br>
Name: &nbsp;<?php echo $result->first_name; echo " ";   echo $result->last_name;?><br/></br>
Email Address: &nbsp;<?php echo $result->email_address; ?><br/></br>
Date of Birth: &nbsp;<br/></br>
Gender: &nbsp;<?php echo $result->gender;   ?><br/></br>
</br></br></br>
Account Information:<br/></br></br>

Username:<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?><br/></br>
Security Question: <?php echo $result->security_question;   ?>&nbsp;<br/></br>
Security Answer: <?php echo $result->security_answer;   ?>&nbsp;<br/></br>
```

Comment: You know, you should use some indentation. Makes your code readable.

Comment: Is your logged in user information, like username is in the post ? Isn't it suppose to be in the `CI` session ?

Comment: Also you can use `$q=$this->db->get();` without the `quotes` and `$data=$row;` should be `$data[]=$row;` in the loop.

Comment: @bažmegakapa sorry :) will do next time

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes. for the username i am using session. but for the email and the name i want it to apper thats why i am using that.

Comment: Then you should be using `$this->session->userdata('username');` in the `where` clause.

Comment: thats what i have in my view form. but what about the email and other information of the logged in user? i cant use session anymore. im trying to get the other information from the database..

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter its usually this, unless you are using a custom authentication library that does it differently.

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('account_id');
```

So you should use

```
$this->db->where('user.id',$this->session->userdata('account_id'));
```

I changed the lookup field from name to id, because you should perform lookups on ID's, because two people may have the same name etc. Lookup of INT's is faster as well.

Comment: i made it unique. but its okay if i still use it like that? to be safe?

Comment: Your table will have an ID column and its a primary key, there it is unique. Why dont you want to use that?

Comment: also you say you get info about the username through `$this->input->post('username')` if so, you should do this after you login as john, just before the where clause do this `die($this->input->post('username'));` This will print the value of the post value and so you can if that value is john etc..

Comment: i can. but i cant use session to get the other information like the name and email. i'll update my question and post the code in my view form. please check. thank you so much! :)

Comment: Okay well, first of all is there a reason you are not using `$this->load->view('viewname, $data);` in your code? You are using the CI super object, which there is no need to do if you just pass the data from the controller to view. Try this way and then let us know.

Comment: wait. i dont have a controller though. i only have a model and view. sorry. im really confused. CI very is new to me.

Comment: if I use `die($this->input->post('username'));` the form wont print at all. where should i put that anyway? please answer back :)

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your db query - your description suggests that every row is being returned (or at least Dennis' row is always being returned).

Your code just loops through all returned rows and prints the last one.

Add some debug code to dump the returned data set before looping through it and refine your query.

Comment: On further thought - you clearly aren't passing any value for username in the POST data. Therefore, your sql may be: SELECT FROM membership WHERE username like '%%' <--- the value of the username POST data. This would return everything.

Comment: oh.. so i should put ('username') there?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$data = array();
foreach($q->result() as $row) {
    $data=$row; // every time $data variable is being updated with new value
}
```

It'll return the last record because every time loop updates the `$data` with new value, if you change it to following

```
$data = array();
foreach($q->result() as $row) {
    $data[]=$row;
}
```

Then it'll keep all the rows as an array in the `$data`.

Alternatively you can use following code without the `foreach` loop

```
$data['result']=$q->result();
```

and in your view you can loop like

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row->name;
     ...
}
```

**Update:** You should use model, view, controller properly. You are using `model` in your `view` but you shouldn't do this. Load and use the `model` in your `controller` and from the controller load the `view` and pass data like,

```
$this->load->view('your_view_name', $data);
```

And `loop` inside the `view` as I mentioned above. Here is another [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888092/return-a-variable-in-my-model-if-the-query-returns-true/12888250#12888250).

Comment: Theres an error that happend. So, what will my command be in the view form? the error says: Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/members_area.php


many lines are affected.

Comment: Sorry. Im confused. I dont have a loop in my view. only in the model.

Comment: i just like to know why this `$data[]=$row;` is giving out an error message saying: _Trying to get property of non-object_

Comment: @Marishka, can you update the `member_here()` function with the details that Sheikth post here?

Comment: @manix i will update as soon as i get the results. :) i'm still trying to do it :) still a bit confused. haha!