# Fetching information from the database MYSQL & Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

the previous question is here incase you guys needed a other information:

[Fetching information from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336744/fetching-information-from-the-database)

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Although all of you have been very helpful. I've managed to get outputs but i'm still **really really confused** lets say that I want to first see the outpurs so im disregarding the controller.

i'll make a controller after i see that my commands are correct :) i dont know why but thats kindo of how i get to understand the whole concept. anyway..

for my 
**membership_model.php**

```
function member_here()
{
$this->db->select('');
$this->db->from('membership');
$this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
$q=$this->db->get('');

if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
$data = array();
foreach($q->result() as $row) {
    $data=$row;
}
return $data;
}
}
```

and my **signup_view.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header')?>

<div align="right"><?php echo anchor('login/signin', 'Login');?></div>

<?php

$option1 = array(
              'name'  => 'What was your childhood nickname?',
              'value'   => 'What was your childhood nickname?'
            );

$option2= array(
    'name'  => 'What is your pet\'s name?',
    'value' => 'What is your pet\s name?'
);

$option3= array(
    'name'  => 'In what city were you born?',
    'value' => 'In what city were you born?'
);

$option4= array(
    'name'  => 'What is the color of your eyes?',
    'value' => 'What is the color of your eyes?'
);

$option5= array(
    'name'  => 'What is your favorite color?',
    'value' => 'What is your favorite color?'
);


echo form_open('login/create_member');
echo "<table width=\"80%\ cellpadding=\"3px\">
<tr>
<td>User Information:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>";
echo "<tr><td>First Name*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name'));
echo "</tr></td>";
echo "<tr><td>Last Name*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name'));
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Email Address*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address'));
echo "</tr></td>";
echo "<tr><td>Gender: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
<?php

echo "</tr></td>";

echo "<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>";
?>



<?php
echo "<table width=\"80%\ cellpadding=\"3px\">
<tr>
<td> Account Information:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Userame*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_input('username', set_value('username'));
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Password*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_password('password');
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Password Confirmation*: </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_password('password2');
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "Security Question*:";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
?>
<select name = "security_question" value="security question">
<option value = "What was your childhood nickname?">What was your childhood nickname?</option>
<option value = "What is your pet's name?">What is your pet's name?</option>
<option value = "In what city were you born?">In what city were you born?</option>
<option value = "What is the color of your eyes?">What is the color of your eyes?</option>
<option value = "What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
</select>

<?php
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "Security Answer*:";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_input('security_answer');
echo "</td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>";
echo form_submit('submit', 'Register');
echo form_reset('reset', 'Reset');
echo "</tr></td>";
echo form_close();

echo "<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>";
?>



<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');?>
```

So, thats all my code. I'm trying to get the first_name, last_name, email_address and all the other information of the **logged in user** to come out from the database.

if i use `$data[]=$row;` instead of `$data=$row;` in my model an error occurs saying this:

`Severity: Notice`

`Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

`Filename: views/members_area.php`

`Line Number: 20`

So, what should I do. *i'm coding without the controller. i'm just checking the results* **thanks!!**

Comment: It's so hard to debug without a controller. But the error have no sence. How you call `member_here()` in the view?

Comment: show the code for views/members_area.php .. specifically line 20..and if you don;t have a controller where do you load the model? $this->load->model("membership_model"); .. and how are you accessing the model function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be clarified:

- A `model` is a entity that persists in the database. In your case: **Membership**
- A `controller` is in charge of load the model, and pass it to the view to be showed
- A `view` only should have html markup, no functions, no logic.

### Database

Assuming that your database have the structure below.

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| id_membership | username  | name       | email              |
+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|             1 | Marishka  | marishkapv | marishka@email.com |
|             2 | johndoe   | John       | john@doe.com       |
|             3 | dennisv   | Dennis     | dennis@v.com       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

### Model

You could build your model `class Membership extends CI_Model` at `/application/models/membership.php` file.

```
class Membership extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function member_here()
    {
        $this->db->select('');
        $this->db->from('membership');
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $q = $this->db->get('');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $data = array();
            foreach($q->result() as $row) 
            {
                $data=$row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

### Controller

Supposing that your have a login page at `example.com/index.php/login`, this should resides at `/application/controllers/login.php` as below:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    public function result()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership');
        $data['member'] = $this->membership->member_here(); 
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Look like the models is loaded throws this two lines:

```
//Load the model in make use of its functions
$this->load->model('membership'); 

//load the row whit the given username
//the result is assigned to array with the key "member", in the view you access this
//value with $member var
$data['member'] = $this->membership->member_here();
```

### Views

As you noted in controller code, there are two views files, `login_view` and `result_view`. The first one will show a html form where you can put the username in order to trigger a select query. The `result_view` show the informacion of the member according to the selected membership

login_view.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action="login/result" method="post">
        Type your username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="submit" value="Load from database" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

result_view.php

```
<h4>Details:</h4>
<p>
Id: <?=$member->id_membership?> <br />
Username: <?=$member->username?> <br />
Email: <?=$member->email?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be very simple read the user guide for more simple examples

```
Model

Class Members Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function member_here()
    {
            $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $query  =   $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
}

Controlelr 

Class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    public function result()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership');
        $data['member'] = $this->membership->member_here(); 
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}

And in View you can simple do it

<?php
foreach($member as $row){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row->id?>"><?php echo $row->name?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```